# Google Speech Api Quota Only on Gloud hosted

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

So, I'm working on some POC stuff for a client. One of the things we need is transcribing large audio recordings to text. We are giving google a try for this as we've had good results using their cloud services in the past.

The issue we keep running into, however, is that we are hitting quotas in test, but not just any quotas. Only quotas on files hosted in our gcloud bucket.

We we send over local files(under the limit for local files), we're fine.

The moment I try to use gcloud to process a larger file, I get this error:

```
Error: Quota exceeded.
```

Comment: I'm now hitting this with files sent from our local file system. We don't even have files in gcloud bucket.